# Crystal report not working after setup installed where .net is not installed

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a windows application using c# .net 2010. I created setup file of that project and installed in client system. Everything is working fine except crystal reports. I thing it is not install properly. please give me some solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install crystal report viewer 13.2.000 on client machine.